# Spring Security JWT - 400 Bad Request : "invalid grant" "Bad credentials"

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently trying to get a JWT Access token via Spring Security.

I am unsure as to why the credentials aren't matching up

**Database**

My data.sql User is pulled from h2-in-memory DB and hibernated into an object using UserDetailsService:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, username, password) VALUES (1, 'joe.bloggs@example.com', '{bcrypt}$2y$10$rHtfxfURj05SoLAwkn9sMO27B9eS7Js0ceh5pyYmrKoyUk.3VPJGi');
```

**Code**

My Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Override
@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder()).and().authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
} 

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
}
```

My Auth server config

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

private String privateKey= "<private key>";
private String publicKey = "<public key>";

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; 

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
}

public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(tokenEnhancer());
}

public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore())
    .accessTokenConverter(tokenEnhancer());

}

public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder =
            PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    String encoded = passwordEncoder.encode("password");

    clients.inMemory().withClient("jwt-example").secret(encoded).scopes("read", "write", "trust")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1*60*60)
    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(6*60*60);
}
}
```

**Postman**

When submitting a postman request with the following

- Authorization

  - Basic Auth

    - username: jwt-example
    - password: [unencrypted-password]
- Headers

  - Authorization: Basic
  - Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body

  - grant_type: password
  - username: Joe.bloggs@example.com
  - password: [unencrypted-password]

I am responded to by the following message:

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

The StackTrace is as follows below:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidGrantException: Bad credentials
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.getOAuth2Authentication(ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.getAccessToken(AbstractTokenGranter.java:70) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:65) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:38) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer$4.grant(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.java:561) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:132) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]

2018-05-08 15:51:59.097 TRACE 3637 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.handleException] returned [<400 Bad Request,error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials",{Cache-Control=[no-store], Pragma=[no-cache]}>]
2018-05-08 15:51:59.098 DEBUG 3637 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials"] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3c8d5564]
2018-05-08 15:51:59.098  WARN 3637 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials"
2018-05-08 15:51:59.098 DEBUG 3637 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-05-08 15:51:59.098 TRACE 3637 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@28bc3d5e]]
2018-05-08 15:51:59.098 DEBUG 3637 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problems.

The first problem was that I was using multiple AuthenticationProviders and when it went to Authenticate it would pass the first time but then go to Authenticate again and fail again and again. this is what cause the Bad Credentials error.

I had written my code like this as I was experiencing a "Encoded password does not look like a BCrypt". This was because I was using a BCrypt password with the prefix '$2y' whereas the BCryptPasswordEncoder only deal with the earlier standard of '$2a.

After experiencing this error I went off on a tangent to implement any other method of JWT token returns I could find not knowing I had implemented multiple providers.

**TL;DR**

- I was using wrong BCrypt password encoding
- I was using multiple AuthenticationProviders